# Creating and re-using map template in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap

I am using ArcMap 10.1 and working on a project which requires 5 different analyses on the same data. I created five map documents (.mxd) and completed my analyses. Now, the problem is that I want to export my results in map format but I want them to be uniform in display i.e. having a same map template. Is there a way to save one of the maps as a template and then use it for creating other 4 maps?

I tried saving one document in 'Map Templates' folder in ArcGis folder but a message box appears which says that I don't have permission to save in that location and I must contact administrator for that, even though I am the only user and administrator of the computer. I don't want to manually add all map elements for 5 different maps, thats too tedious!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The help page on [Using Map Templates](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s90000002w000000) explains it quite well.

Here are three different ways you can go about rectifying this.

1. From the help, it appears that you need to make a change in the registry to save in `<install drive>:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\MapTemplates`. By changing it via [ArcMapAdvancedSettings.exe](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/0003/000300000018000000.htm), all users can access the templates. (Not really useful in your instance.)
2. You can save the mxd to a different location and create a folder in MapTemplates. Then just copy the mxd into that new folder and it will appear as a template.
3. The easiest way is to save it in `%APPDATA%\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcMap\Templates`. Only one user can access these templates, but in your case, you'll be the only person.

If you also want to apply a template you have created to an existing map, first have that map open and then click the **Change Layout** button on the **Layout** toolbar to open the **Select Template** dialog box.

Comment: I tried options 1 and 2 but still get the message that I don't have permission to change the templates location OR to save in a newly created folder in MapTemplates folder. I have checked the user accounts in control panel which show that my account has administrative rights. Please clarify if I am missing anything and also explain what is %APPDATA% ?

Comment: @UmairDurrani Hmm, option two worked for me, and I'm the only user on my computer. Did you create a folder in Windows Explorer (outside of ArcMap entirely) and try copying the mxd there? As for `%APPDATA%`, look [here](http://best-windows.vlaurie.com/environment-variables.html).