# Bringing layout into another drawing using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, import, layouts

I am using ArcMap 10.1.  I set up a layout view (a titleblock) and would like to bring it into another mxd file.

How do you do this?

If you are familiar with Autocad this would be the equivalent of importing a titleblock.

Comment: Check this out:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67177/how-to-create-and-re-use-my-own-map-template-in-arcmap-10-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a template. Any mxd-file can be converted to a template and this is how you do it:

1. Open the mxd you want to convert in ArcMap
2. Save a copy `file -> save a copy`
3. Save it in the following folder: `%APPDATA%\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcMap\Templates`
4. Done!

Now open a new map document in ArcMap (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>).

Next to the blank template your freshly saved template will be available. Choose this one and your layout is available in the new document.

Comment: Well then you're just saving the entire mapdocument into the default templates folder. That's not what the OP is asking, he wants a lightweight titleblock that is NOT an mxd file, but that he can import into an mxd file...

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by creating templates.  [ESRI documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s90000002w000000)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to :

1-create your layout template;

2-select the layout elements (using the "select elements" cursor);

3-Copy the layout elements and to past them in the layout view of your target MXD file;

You may have to drag the data frame into the layout view (causing a double).

My Arc license is located on a distant server and I couldn't find my way to where Stefan was pointing in order to resolve a similar situation as the one Matt was faced with, so I just tried this and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

In ArcMap 10.8.1 Basic:

1. Open the MXD that you want to change
2. Ensure ‘Layout’ toolbar is visible (Customize / Toolbars / Layout)
3. Click ‘Change Layout’ button
4. Click ‘Open’ button at bottom-right above ‘Cancel’ button
5. Navigate to and open MXD that you want to use the layout from
6. Click through the data frame options as needed then click ‘Finish’